# Is it possible to disable ASP ViewState via POST or in cookies?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I know you can disable ViewState via the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876953/is-it-possible-to-disable-viewstate-in-asp-net), but I'm wondering if it's possible to disable it via a form input from a client.

For example can you POST a value like `disable_view_state=1` or in cookies or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.When the page first renders viewstate will always be there unless you disable viewstate at the control level or at page level.

1. Since viewstate is already there, you cannot suddenly disable it by
   any means;
2. ASP.Net will always look for the initial viewstate of page when you
   post back since it needs the viewstate to do page processing.

Your best bet is to disable it at the page level by using following page directive at top of page markup, so when page first renders it doesn't have viewstate. Note that `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` setting in page directive for disabling view state for all control in the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RepeaterPage.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="RepeaterPage"  ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```